# Route Handlers Inside a Class

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have a Sinatra app setup where most of the logic is performed inside of various classes, and the `post`/`get` routes instantiate those classes and call their methods.

I'm thinking about whether putting the `post`/`get` route handlers inside of the classes themselves would be a better structure.

In any case, I'd like to know if it is possible. So for instance:

```
class Example
  def say_hello
    "Hello"
  end

  get '/hello' do
    @message = say_hello
  end
end
```

Without modification to the above, Sinatra will say there is no method `say_hello` on the `SinatraApplication` object.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You just need to inherit from `Sinatra::Base`:

```
require "sinatra/base"

class Example < Sinatra::Base
  def say_hello
    "Hello"
  end

  get "/hello" do
    say_hello
  end
end
```

You can run your app with `Example.run!`.

---

If you need more separation between parts of your application, just make another Sinatra app. Put shared functionality in model classes and helpers, and run all your apps together with Rack.

```
module HelloHelpers
  def say_hello
    "Hello"
  end
end

class Hello < Sinatra::Base
  helpers HelloHelpers

  get "/?" do
    @message = say_hello
    haml :index
  end
end

class HelloAdmin < Sinatra::Base
  helpers HelloHelpers

  get "/?" do
    @message = say_hello
    haml :"admin/index"
  end
end
```

**config.ru:**

```
map "/" do
  run Hello
end

map "/admin" do
  run HelloAdmin
end
```

Install [Thin](http://code.macournoyer.com/thin/), and run your app with `thin start`.

Comment: Thanks! My goal is basically to create multiple controllers. I'm not sure how best to do that in this way -- since one class runs as the entire app when using the run method? Any suggestions?

Comment: Just updated my answer to include an example of one way you can split your application into multiple classes.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use [Sinatra Helpers](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Helpers).

Comment: This is a broken link. Here are docs on Sinatra Helpers http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Helpers