# Sinatra doesn't know this ditty

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Here's my `faxattach.rb` code:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'docsplit'
require './sinatra/faxattach_helpers'

class FaxAttach < Sinatra::Base
  helpers Sinatra::FaxAttachHelpers

      get '/*' do
        "hello world"
        status 405
      end

      put '/*' do
        status 405
      end

      patch '/*' do
        status 405
      end

      delete '/*' do
        status 405
      end

      options '/*' do
        status 405
      end

      link '/*' do
        status 405
      end

      unlink '/*' do
        status 405
      end

      post '/process' do
        path = params[:path]
        begin
          debugger
          file = test_download path
        rescue
          status 404
        end

        debugger
        code = extractCode file
        code
      end

    end
```

I'm doing a post request to /process using curl `curl --data "path=URL_HERE" localhost:4567/process`, and for some reason I'm getting: `Sinatra doesn't know this ditty`. It's telling me to put in a `post /process` which I clearly have.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sinatra: Route Handlers Inside a Class - Access other Class Methods](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791320/sinatra-route-handlers-inside-a-class-access-other-class-methods). You need a `config.ru` file that specifies what class to run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `ruby faxattach.rb` with a modular app if you add the following line to the *end of the class* (:

```
run! if __FILE__ == $0
```

`$0` is the executed file.

`__FILE__` is the current file.

For example:

```
require "sinatra/base"

class App < Sinatra::Base
  get '/' do
    "App is running."
  end
  # add more endpoints...

  # ...then add run! to run if the
  # file has been executed directly.
  # It should be last.
  run! if __FILE__ == $0
end
```

Comment: and here is one important moment - you should to add it AFTER your endpoints declared. I've spent a lot of time to find it out :-(

Comment: @RuslanValeev Sorry about that, I've added a further example so that (I hope) it's clearer and no one else suffers your fate.

Answer (score 2):

Got it, the issue was that I was starting the app with `ruby faxattach.rb` instead of `rackup`.